# .Net calling Java Webservice, I need to convert an XMLSchema/long to anXMLSoap/long

Tags: java, .net, web-services, soap, interop

I am using C# with .net 4 and am trying to consume a java webservice.  My code was autogenerated by adding a .net 2.0 style webservice reference.  I believe there is an issue with the types .net is sending to the java webservice, here is the exception I receive when I attempt to connect:

```
Internal Server Error (deserialization error: deserialization error: unexpected element type: expected={http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}long, actual={http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}long)
```

Old documentation from the webservice: 
When serializing objects to SOAP messages, the Microsoft .NET platform maps all primitives to W3C XML
schema types. This, in conjunction with the .NET platforms inability to differentiate primitives from primitive
wrappers (through auto-boxing) causes an interoperability problem with Sun One web services when using
encoded RPC SOAP messages.
In the Java programming language primitives and their equivalent object wrappers cannot be auto-boxed
thus are differentiated in the language.
When the web services are generated and deployed under Sun One, the server side WSDL maps Java
primitives to the W3C schema type and maps Java Objects to the SOAP schema type.

Does anyone know how I can tell .net to send a http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/}long instead of a http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}long?

Thanks!
AFrieze

Comment: How did you code/get your client in C# ? Did you autogenerate it ? What is the wsdl like ? Is it doc style or rpc style ? give some details

Comment: I added some more details Bhaskar...hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to try changing the style to `Document`. This way , when you generate the wsdl , you will find a `<type></type>` section listing all data types used by the service. This section will also have a `namespace` element that is essentially what is causing the problem right now with you, but which is not apparent because with RPC style of service , wsdl does not contain a section for types. I am assuming the `encoding` is `literal`.

edit :

I should have guessed it first , but it seems like your service uses `encoded` types rather than `literal`. A thing about encoded services is that they are always prone to interoperability issues. My recommendation : Do not use rpc/encoded - use Document/Literal.

Comment: Hi Bhaskar,  I'm looking at the generated wsdl file and I do see a types section.  The type of the variable throwing the error is set to "soap-enc:long"  which should be correct.  When .net calls the service, however, it is not sending the soap version of a long.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I also just added some documentation from the webservice to the original question which may help.

Comment: Hi Bhaskar.  I do not have any control over the webservice :(  I'm just trying to consume it from .net